# Populating an UICollectionView to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to populate a collection view with data from a Firebase Database. I'm making following call in my viewdidload function:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Profiles")

handle = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: title!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    var items: [Profiles] = []

    if snapshot.value is NSNull {

       print("NIL!!")

    } else {
       for item in snapshot.children {

           let profile = Profiles(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)

               items.append(profile)
           }

            self.profiles = items
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and the compiler highlights the following piece of code:

```
handle = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: title!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

I'm not understanding what the issue is, and dont understand how to fix it?!

Comment: Most likely your `title` has a `nil` value and it's throwing off the error because you're force-unwrapping it. `print(title)` before the query statement and check if it has a non-nil value

Comment: @ThunderStruct title is a json pair in the firebase database which does have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing the `UIViewController`'s `title` member with the Firebase child you're using the query for. If you have a child named `title` in your data structure and want to query based on that, just replace your query statement with this:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "title").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    // your code
})
```

The only way you'd get the error you're getting is if the variable you're using (`title`) has nil.